# How to change text color in RangePicker in Ant design?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd, daterangepicker

Im currently working with Range Picker in antd package, it has a style prop that helps me to modify the style, but I can't change the text colour, is there anyway to do it?

```
import moment from 'moment'

const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

  <RangePicker
          style={{
               color: "orange",}}
               className='range-picker'
               format={'DD-MM-YYYY'}
              }}
          />
```

[image: Date Picker component]

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is still relevant

Using CSS or CSS Modules:

To change the text color inside the input of the RangePicker, you can target the specific class names provided by Ant Design.

```
.ant-picker-input > input::placeholder {
    color: orange; 
}

.ant-picker-input > input {
    color: orange;
}
```

If you're using CSS Modules, remember to use the :global selector to target these global class names.